# Logic Apps - Different JSON schemas giving different possibilities in subsequent actions

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm parsing some JSON in Logic Apps.  Why are these two JSON schemas treated differently.  How can I amend the second to match the first?
With this JSON I can see the variable like success when I create a new step based on the parsed JSON.

```
<code>
{
"properties": {
    "params": {
        "properties": {
            "WOPARTSOPT": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "WOPARTSOPT"
        ],
        "title": "The Params Schema",
        "type": "object"
    },
    "success": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"required": [
    "success",
    "params"
],
"title": "The Root Schema",
"type": "object"
}
</code>

With this JSON I can't see the variable like success when I create a new step based on the parsed 
JSON.

<code>
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"properties": {
    "Payload": {
        "items": [
            {
                "properties": {
                    "PR_ADD1": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "PR_ADD1"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            }
        ],
        "type": "array"
    }
},
"required": [
    "Payload"
],
"type": "object"
}
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my understanding, the second json schema doesn't have the properties of "success", so it can not be used to parse the json data which has a property of "success". So this is the reason for why you can't see the variable "success" in your next steps.

By the way, why did you want to amend the second schema to match the first ? We can generate the json schema by click the "Use sample payload to generate schema" button and input the json string into it, it will generate the schema automatically.
[image]

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know. I will try my best to provide the solution~